# How can I aggregate wireless signals to increase speed?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a laptop with winXP sp3.

I read about a utility about 2 years ago that would let you connect to multiple wireless networks by creating a bunch of virtual wireless adapters and combining them into one connection.

Well, I am staying in a hotel in a densely populated area, and there are a like 7 seperate free public access points that I can connect to, but each one is pretty slow.

Now that I actually need to use this software to combine these things, I can't find it.

Anyone know what I'm talking about or how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you refer to [Wireless Bonding](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/sb/CS-025343.htm).

[802.11n and channel bonding](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless/f/80211n-300-mbps.htm) reference, and a [Linux reference](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6382/1/).

> [**802.11n**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n), bonding utilizes two adjacent Wi-Fi channels simultaneously to double the bandwidth of the wireless link compared to 802.11b/g.

Comment: I don't know why is this accepted as an answer but it doesn't sound like what the OP is looking for at all. @Ronnie is looking for a way to connect to multiple wifi access points simultaneously using one physical wifi adapter and making all those connections appear as one. Wifi bonding is a feature offered by 802.11n to allow for higher bandwidth throughput to just *one* n-enabled AP -- there is no connection to multiple AP's here.